# How does Giriko's 'Time Tells No Lies' Fullbring work?

Tags: bleach

I have read the [wiki](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Tells_No_Lies#Fullbring) on his power but it still does not make sense to me. I would argue that the way Giriko's Fullbring works is very inconsistent, but am hoping for a decent explanation. The first time we see his power, he attaches a timer to a box while training Ichigo. The next time we see it, he shoots projectiles at Ginjo. The third time, he uses a dial on his shoulder to get massive (big and green like hulk it seemed to reference).

**Question**: How does his power *actually* work? Is there some link to each of this uses that I missed? Can you give me an answer that is not full of loopholes?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the way he states it, he can create "contracts" with set time limits.
The contracts seem to extend to anything and everything with a spirit.

as the fullbringers state "Everything has a soul". he makes a contract with the box to trap ichigo inside, the next is the energy, he makes a contract with the air to fire it at rapid speeds (energy) at ginjo, then finally after he is wearing his fullbring he makes a contract with his own body to become "invincible" as he states...

"Time tells no lies"
ie, within this set time period everything I say is true.

I don't have much to back this up with, it's just as logical as I could think of.

Answer (score 1):

I think that his fullbring gives him the ability to make contracts about anything which makes him extremly strong. However, if he breaks or changes it, he will lose a body part. It is like a strong sword with double edges, at least logically.